# Consume JSON Object in PUT Restful Service

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb, jersey

I'm trying to implement a RESTful Service in Java that receives a JSON Object through a PUT request and automatically maps into a Java Object. I managed to do this in XML, but I can't do it using JSON. Here's what I want to do:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String putTodo(JAXBElement<Route> r) {
    Route route = r.getValue();
    route.toString();
    System.out.println("Received PUT XML Request");
    return "ok";
}
```

This works, but using JSON would be something similar, but I can't use JAXB, can I?

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String putTodo(<WHAT DO I PUT HERE>) {
    Route route = r.getValue();
    route.toString();
    System.out.println("Received PUT JSON Request");
    return "ok";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Jersey will use JAXB to process the JSON messages by leveraging the [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/) library.

So you can do the following:

```
@PUT
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String putTodo(JAXBElement<Route> r) {
    Route route = r.getValue();
    route.toString();
    System.out.println("Received PUT XML/JSON Request");
    return "ok";
}
```

For More Information on Using Jettison with JAXB:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison-namespace.html

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Maybe I wasn't specifying the MediaType in the invocation of the service ;) thanks